# Amplify Datastore reachability false in Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

Working on a React Native Expo project, I am fetching data using `DataStore.query` to my `amplify` backend.

```
const fetchRestaurants = async () => {
        const results = await DataStore.query(Restaurant)
        setRestaurants(results)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchRestaurants()
    }, [])
```

For iOS, I get:

```
iOS Bundling complete 53ms
 LOG  [INFO] 49:57.609 Reachability - subscribing to reachability in React Native
 LOG  [INFO] 50:58.504 Reachability - Notifying reachability change true
```

However for Android, I get:

```
Android Bundling complete 73ms
 LOG  [INFO] 50:58.358 Reachability - subscribing to reachability in React Native
 LOG  [INFO] 51:58.380 Reachability - Notifying reachability change false
```

The `Notifying reachability` for android is `false`, as a result it fails to fetch any data from the backend. For iOS it works.